# How to gray out menu item in Android ICS (Setting -> Security -> Screen Lock)?

Tags: android, locking, screen, device, administrator

I am developing an application for ICS with a Device Administrator. I need to gray out the menu selection “Screen Lock” under Setting -> Security, and if not possible to gray out the Face Unlock, Pattern, Pin and Password under Setting -> Security -> Screen Lock.

I am out after the program code that doing it, either Java or XML.

Thanks in advance

Joel

Answer (score 0):

Preventing the user access to the screen lock is analogous to preventing the user access to his or her device. Thankfully, these sorts of hacks aren't possible in Android (even through Device Administrator). Sorry.

Comment: And BTW, even if you could find a security loophole that allowed you to do this, the user could just boot the device into safe mode and uninstall your third party app... so it wouldn't be secure at all. :)

Comment: When I configure the mail application using Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync on ICS some of the items under screen lock get disabled. This happens first when the new installed device administrator is activated. This means it is possible to do it without any security violation.

Comment: Unless Microsoft Exchange Active Sync is a system app, the user could just boot into safe mode and uninstall, correct?